# Color gradient for bars in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gradient

I want that each bar in my diagram has a color gradient from black to white (from left to the right). However, for the following code, the gradient exists for the entire diagram such that the left bar is black, the middle one is gray, and the right one is white.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[ybar] 
        \addplot[left color=black,right color=white] coordinates {(1,2) (2,3) (3,4)}; 
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, that's going to be difficult. You could plot each bar with its own `\addplot` command, but that might not be feasible depending on how many data points you have.

Comment: Just from personal interest:why does one want to do so? For me the plot presented by @Jake in the answer below looks quite terrible and does not add any obvious advantage or improvement.

Comment: @BenediktBauer: I agree, those shadings are definitely out of place in scientific graphs and don't add any information to the visualisation. However, as [Martin Tapankov said](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1884/2552), "People should be free to shoot themselves in the foot, if they so choose".

Comment: @Jake that's absolutely right. My comment also was not thought to offend you or your solution. I just took it as an example that illustrates (or better does not illustrate) the use of shaded bars. Therefore I was asking myself what progress someone would expect from such a feature.

Answer (score 6):

One workaround is be to use error bars for the shading. This works because each error bar uses a separate path, so the shading applies to the bars individually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[ybar, ymin=0] 
        \addplot[
            draw=none, fill=none,
            error bars/y dir=minus,
            error bars/y fixed relative=1,
            error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={
                \fill[xshift=-6pt, left color=black, right color=white, draw=black] ##1 ++(12pt,0pt) rectangle ##2;}
         ] coordinates {(1,2) (2,3) (3,4)}; 
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

ATTENTION: this answer refers to something which is not part of any stable release at the time of this writing.

---

Recently, I added switches to the bar plot handler of the PGF developer version. It allows to inject custom code `at begin bar` and `at end bar`.

This allows to write

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[ybar]
        \addplot[left color=black,right color=white,
            at begin bar={%
                \begin{scope}%
                \shade\pgfextra
            },
            at end bar={%
                \endpgfextra;
                \end{scope}%
            },
        ]
            coordinates {(1,2) (2,3) (3,4)}; 
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Eventually, there will be styles to simplify such constructs.