# How to draw Area Charts

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I want to draw an area chart, something like this

[image]
I dont know how to fill the area with colors, here is what I have

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}


\makeatletter
\let\percent\@percentchar
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        %title = {Distinctive SIFT features vs. Image resolution},
        xlabel= X LABEL HERE, 
        ylabel= {Y LABEL HERE},
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
        legend style={
                at={(0.5,-0.15)},               
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1
        },
        width=12.8cm,
        height=8cm,
        point meta={x*100},
        symbolic x coords={100\percent, 90\percent, 79\percent, 69\percent, 60\percent, 50\percent, 39\percent, 30\percent, 20\percent},
        %grid=major
]
% Median
\addplot coordinates {
(100\percent, 7218) (90\percent, 6075) (79\percent, 4021) (69\percent, 2906) (60\percent, 1861) (50\percent, 768) (39\percent, 451) (30\percent, 317) (20\percent, 164)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See PGF manual, Tikz Shadings library, p. 412

Comment: @ajeh: No, not really.

Comment: @wererabit: Is this really a simple gradient, or does the color depend on the `y` coordinate?

Comment: @ajeh: The question you linked to [Color gradient for bars in pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73845/color-gradient-for-bars-in-pgfplots) is about gradients on bars, this is about an area fill. Even though the answer is the same, the question is quite different. I think anyone new to tikz would be confused if they ended up at the linked question when looking to fill an area under a curve with a gradient.

Comment: @PeterGrill They work the same, thus the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\closedcycle` and specify a fill color. To get a gradient going from top to bottom, you can specify `top color=` and `bottom color=`. For a gradient going from left to right you specify `left color=` and `right color`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I also changed `\addplot` to `\addplot+` so that the `fill` option is appended to the existing options.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}


\makeatletter
\let\percent\@percentchar
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        %title = {Distinctive SIFT features vs. Image resolution},
        xlabel= X LABEL HERE, 
        ylabel= {Y LABEL HERE},
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
        legend style={
                at={(0.5,-0.15)},               
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1
        },
        width=12.8cm,
        height=8cm,
        point meta={x*100},
        symbolic x coords={100\percent, 90\percent, 79\percent, 69\percent, 60\percent, 50\percent, 39\percent, 30\percent, 20\percent},
        %grid=major
]
% Median
\addplot+  [left color=green, right color=red] coordinates {
(100\percent, 7218) (90\percent, 6075) (79\percent, 4021) (69\percent, 2906) (60\percent, 1861) (50\percent, 768) (39\percent, 451) (30\percent, 317) (20\percent, 164)} \closedcycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to change the color to a gradient of colors (going from say green to red)?

Comment: @wererabit: Updated solution to include a color gradient.